# Proof of the normal equations theorem

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming

> **Thm:** Let the minimization problem be: $$ \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\| Ay - b\|_{2}^{2}} = \| Ax - b\|_{2}^{2}$$
>
> the problem admits a solution if and only if: $$ A^{\mathrm{ T }}Ax = A^{\mathrm{ T }}b$$
>
> with A a tall matrix: $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$
>
> b a vector: $ b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$
>
> and $m \geq n$

I wanted to demonstrate this theorem and I proceded this way so far:

$$ \| Ay - b\|_{2}^{2} = (Ay - b)^{\mathrm{ T }}(Ay - b) = (y^{\mathrm{ T }}A^{\mathrm{ T }} - b^{\mathrm{ T }})(Ay - b) = y^{\mathrm{ T }}A^{\mathrm{ T }}Ay - y^{\mathrm{ T }}A^{\mathrm{ T }}b - b^{\mathrm{ T }}Ay + b^{\mathrm{ T }}b \tag{*}\label{*} $$

Now calculate the derivative with respect to $y$ and impose it to be equal to zero

This is where I'm having problems.

I tried and this is what I get:

$$ \frac{ d }{ dy }\eqref{*} = 2A^{\mathrm{ T }}Ay - b^{\mathrm{ T }}A - b^{\mathrm{ T }}A $$

imposing it to be eqal to zero:

$$ 2A^{\mathrm{ T }}Ay - b^{\mathrm{ T }}A - b^{\mathrm{ T }}A = 0 $$

I get

$$ A^{\mathrm{ T }}Ax = b^{\mathrm{ T }}A$$

which is different from the **Theorem**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $$2A^{\mathrm{ T }}Ay - b^{\mathrm{ T }}A - b^{\mathrm{ T }}A$$ is wrong because you are subtracting row vectors from a column vector.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, you are right, I didn't think about that. So the derivatives of $ y^{\mathrm{ T }}A^{\mathrm{ T }}b $ and $ b^{\mathrm{ T }}Ay $ both are equals to $A^{\mathrm{ T }}b$ right?

Comment: Yes. Note that the derivative of $\rm c^\top y$ with respect to $\rm y$ is $\rm c$. In this case, $\rm c = A^\top b$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you very much. I now understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than expanding the function into 4 separate terms as your first step, you should collect everything into a single term. Differentiate that, and perform a change-of-variables as you proceed. This approach greatly reduces the visual clutter.

Define $x=(Ay-b).\,\,$ The function is then simple to differentiate
$$\eqalign{
 f &= x:x \cr
df &= 2x:dx \,\,\,= 2x:A\,dy \,\,\,= 2A^Tx:dy \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= 2A^Tx \cr
}$$ where colon represents the inner/Frobenius product, i.e. $A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$. For vector arguments, it is simply the dot product.

Set the gradient to zero to obtain
$$\eqalign{
  A^Tx = 0 \cr
 A^T(Ay-b) = 0\cr
 A^TAy = A^Tb \cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

As all terms are scalars, you can transpose them.

$$y^TA^Tb+b^TAy=2y^TA^Tb.$$

Comment: How does this help me? What terms are scalars? The results of the derivation are column vectors.

Comment: @LucaAngioloni: are you kidding ?

Comment: No, I probably misunderstood your answer. I'm sorry if I said something wrong.

Comment: @LucaAngioloni Yves is correct. Although the term $(Ay - b)$ is a column vector, when you multiply it by its transpose, you are effectively dot producting the vector with itself and so you end up with a scalar. Since that scalar is the sum of $4$ terms when you expand it out, all $4$ terms must themselves be scalars, including the terms mentioned in this answer.